# I can't import emotion js style with dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, emotion

I have a webpage that looks like this:
[image]

This is my `_app.tsx` file:

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { createTheme } from '@arwes/design'
import { ThemeProvider, Global, css } from '@emotion/react'
import { globalStyles } from '../shared/styles.js'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const theme = createTheme();
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      {globalStyles}
      <div style={{
          marginBottom: theme.space(2),
          borderBottom: `${theme.outline(2)}px solid ${theme.palette['primary'].main}`,
          padding: theme.space(2),
          backgroundColor: theme.palette.neutral.elevate(2),
          textShadow: `0 0 ${theme.shadowBlur(1)}px ${theme.palette['primary'].main}`,
          color: theme.palette['primary'].main
      }}>
        Futuristic Sci-Fi UI Web Framework
      </div>

      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

And this is `shared/styles.js`:

```
import { css, Global, keyframes } from '@emotion/react'
import styled from '@emotion/styled'

export const globalStyles = (
  <Global
    styles={css`
      html,
      body {
        margin: 0;
        background: papayawhip;
        min-height: 100%;
        font-size: 24px;
      }
    `}
  />
)

export const blueOnBlack = (theme) => css`
  marginBottom: ${theme.space(2)};
  borderBottom: ${theme.outline(2)}px solid ${theme.palette['primary'].main};
  padding: ${theme.space(2)};
  backgroundColor: ${theme.palette.neutral.elevate(2)};
  textShadow: 0 0 ${theme.shadowBlur(1)}px ${theme.palette['primary'].main};
  color: ${theme.palette['primary'].main};
`
```

Notice that `blueOnBlack` is an attempt to put the `Futuristic Sci-Fi UI Web Framework` style into its own importable variable.

The problem is that when I put `blueOnBlack` into the `_app.tsx` as the style for the `Futuristic Sci-Fi UI Web Framework` div tag, it fails.

This is `_app.tsx` with `blueOnBlack` imported:

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { createTheme } from '@arwes/design'
import { ThemeProvider, Global, css } from '@emotion/react'
import { globalStyles, blueOnBlack } from '../shared/styles.js'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const theme = createTheme();
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      {globalStyles}
      <div style={blueOnBlack(theme)}>
        Futuristic Sci-Fi UI Web Framework
      </div>

      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

The resulting webpage looks like this,
[image]

It's almost right... but it dropped the background color. Why is it different?

Comment: You forgot to wrap that expression in `${...}`: `backgroundColor: ${theme.palette.neutral.elevate(2)};`. Same with `padding`. Right now you are setting the background color *literally* to "theme.palette.neutral.elevate(2)", which is not a valid color.

Comment: Oh good catch! That's weird though. I fixed `padding: ${theme.space(2)};` and `backgroundColor: ${theme.palette.neutral.elevate(2)};` but it still gives the same result aka no black background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `shared/styles.js` from:

```
import { css, Global, keyframes } from '@emotion/react'
import styled from '@emotion/styled'

export const globalStyles = (
  <Global
    styles={css`
      html,
      body {
        margin: 0;
        background: papayawhip;
        min-height: 100%;
        font-size: 24px;
      }
    `}
  />
)

export const blueOnBlack = (theme) => css`
  marginBottom: ${theme.space(2)};
  borderBottom: ${theme.outline(2)}px solid ${theme.palette['primary'].main};
  padding: ${theme.space(2)};
  backgroundColor: ${theme.palette.neutral.elevate(2)};
  textShadow: 0 0 ${theme.shadowBlur(1)}px ${theme.palette['primary'].main};
  color: ${theme.palette['primary'].main};
`
```

to this:

```
import { css, Global, keyframes } from '@emotion/react'
import styled from '@emotion/styled'

export const globalStyles = (
  <Global
    styles={css`
      html,
      body {
        margin: 0;
        background: papayawhip;
        min-height: 100%;
        font-size: 24px;
      }
    `}
  />
)

export const blueOnBlack = (theme) => styled.div={
  marginBottom: theme.space(2),
  borderBottom: theme.outline(2) + 'px solid' + theme.palette['primary'].main,
  padding: theme.space(2),
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.neutral.elevate(2),
  textShadow: '0 0 ' + theme.shadowBlur(1) + 'px ' + theme.palette['primary'].main,
  color: theme.palette['primary'].main
}
```

And then it ran and gave me the correct styling including the black background on the text. Notice that I'm using `styled.div` instead of `css`